# How to split a list based on distinct element

Tags: r, list, split, unique

I would like to split a list according to each distinct element

```
mylist <- list("first","first","second")

### What I would like
# A first list
list("first","first")
# A second list
list("second")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do the one-liner:

```r
list2env(split(mylist, unlist(mylist)), globalenv())
```

Then you have the two lists in your global environment:

```r
dput(first)
#> list("first", "first")

dput(second)
#> list("second")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You can split your dataframe according to unique values:

```r
newlist <- split(mylist, match(mylist, unique(unlist(mylist))))
newlist

# $`1`
# $`1`[[1]]
# [1] "first"
# 
# $`1`[[2]]
# [1] "first"
# 
# 
# $`2`
# $`2`[[1]]
# [1] "second"
```

Then, use `list2env` to add the list to your environment:

```r
list2env(newlist, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: `split(mylist, unlist(mylist))` should do the trick

Comment: Indeed! way simpler :)

Comment: `split(mylist, match(mylist, unique(mylist)))` this should be the desired answer in case the list has many elements in it

Comment: @zx8754 seems allan just posted that as an answer.

Comment: @onyambu it is OK, just didn't want the good solution to be buried in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply()` to make a nested list of lists of each unique element:

```
mylist2 <- lapply(unique(mylist), \(x) mylist[mylist == x])

mylist2
```

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "first"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "first"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "second"
```